# Finding values in a dict that meet a certain criterion

Tags: python, dictionary

If I have a dict as follows:

```
d = {"1,2" : 3, "1,3" : 6, "1,4" : 5,
          "2,3" : 5, "2,4" : 6,
          "3,4" : 9,}
```

I am trying to find all triplets that meet this criterion:

```
d["a,b"] < d["a,c"] == d["b,c"]
```

The tricky part is that a, b, and c can be shuffled until the criterion is met. 
Is there  a simple way to do this?

Comment: Can you please explain the criterion?

Comment: Also, can you make the keys tuples instead of strings, e.g. `(1,2)` instead of `"1,2"`?

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr, `x < y == z` in Python *means* `x < y and y == z` - look up "chained comparisons".

Comment: @TimPeters Good point, had a brain fart. Deleted. I still think its an odd comparison to be making.

Answer (score 2):

```
d = {"1,2" : 3, "1,3" : 6, "1,4" : 5,
          "2,3" : 5, "2,4" : 6,
          "3,4" : 9,}
import itertools
for item in itertools.combinations(d.keys(), 3):
    if d[item[0]] < d[item[1]] == d[item[2]]:
        print d[item[0]], d[item[1]], d[item[2]]
```

**Output**

```
5 6 6
3 6 6
```

**Using list comprehension:**

```
import itertools
print [(d[item[0]], d[item[1]], d[item[2]])
        for item in itertools.combinations(d.keys(), 3)
        if d[item[0]] < d[item[1]] == d[item[2]]]
```

**Output**

```
[(5, 6, 6), (3, 6, 6)]
```

Comment: I don't think this quite fits what the OP is asking for. The OP asked for triples where `d["a,b"] < d["a,c"] == d["b,c"]`. Both returned values have 4 values (`1,2,3,4`) not 3 (`a,b,c)`) as hinted in the comparator.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr You are right. I fixed that in the solution now. Please check that.

Comment: Not quite. In your original you had an answer of `('1,4', '1,3', '2,4')`. If `a,b=1,4`, and `a,c=1,3` then `b,c` **must equal** `1,4`, not `2,4` as your solution provided. I have a solution below, but there are no triplets that match the OPs given condition, which makes this harder.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Are you sure we are comparing the keys? I dont think so. `d["a,b"] < d["a,c"] == d["b,c"]`. We are comparing the values of the dictionary.

Comment: You need to compare the values, but the keys aren't as simple as you made out. You need to find three values, `a,b,c` such that `d["a,b"] < d["a,c"] == d["b,c"]`. Re-read my last comment, and you'll find your answer isn't valid to what the OP asks for.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr Can we take that as, the question is not clear?

Answer (score 2):

This should match what the OP asked for, but is possibly not what they need. *edit: now with just one loop*

```
d = {"1,2" : 3, "1,3" : 6, "1,4" : 5,
          "2,3" : 5, "2,4" : 6,
          "3,4" : 9,
      "a,b" : 1, "a,c" : 2, "b,c": 2
    }

parts = set(",".join(d.keys()).split(',')) # Get all parts of the keys
import itertools
for a,b,c in itertools.permutations(parts,3):
    # Get each possible permutation of a,b,c
    try:
        # Try and find an item that matches the condition
        if d[",".join([a,b])] < d[",".join([a,c])] == d[",".join([b,c])]:
            print (a,b,c)
    except KeyError:
        pass # keyerror
```

The problem is this returns nothing as there are no triplets that match that condition. I've added an additional set of keys to give *an* output of literally `('a', 'b', 'c')` to show it works.

Comment: can you explain what .join is doing?

Comment: Just noting that if all you *intend* to catch is `KeyError`, far better to write `except KeyError:` ;-)

Comment: @TimPeters I indended to get the quickest answer ;) But thanks :)

Comment: @user2767074 `string.join(t,a)` takes all the elements of array `a` and inserts string `t` between each element. If `a` only has one thing, it just returns a string representation of `a`.